# snwoflake weird date issue with rolling quarters on custom period

Tags: time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rolling-computation, dateadd

I can't calculate rolling quarters with a custom period table:

| Period |
| --- |
| 2017-06-01 |
| 2020-12-01 |
| 2020-11-01 |

**Rolling month and years are working**:

```
  DATEADD(MONTH, -2, "Period") AS "Period M-2"
  DATEADD(YEAR, -1, "Period") AS "Period Y-1"
```

When i **query quarters** with **current_date()** this is **working**:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, current_date()))
```

When i query my table with

```
DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, "Period")  AS "Period Q-1"
```

I have the following results (it seems calculating M-3 instead quarters):

| Period | Period Q-1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-01 | 2017-05-01 |
| 2017-09-01 | 2017-06-01 |
| 2017-10-01 | 2017-07-01 |

To reproduce the issue:

```
WITH input AS (select $1 "Period" from values 
('2017-08-01'),
('2017-09-01'),
('2017-10-01'),
('2017-05-01'),
('2020-11-01'),
('2020-11-01'),
('2017-04-01'),
('2020-10-01'),
('2020-10-01')
)
SELECT "Period",
DATE(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, "Period" )) AS  "Period M-1",
DATE(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, "Period" )) AS  "Period M-2",
DATE(DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, "Period" )) AS  "Period Q-1",
DATE(DATEADD(QUARTER, -2, "Period" )) AS  "Period Q-2",
DATE(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, "Period" )) AS  "Period Y-1",
DATE(DATEADD(YEAR, -2, "Period" )) AS  "Period Y-2"
FROM input
```

**UPDATE**:
This is working with this formula, thank you for explanations @Francesco.

```
  DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',DATEADD('DAY', -1, DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', "Period"))) AS "Period Q1"
```

But Q2 & Q3 still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
DATEADD(QUARTER, -<value>, <date> )
```

is equivalent to

```
DATEADD(MONTH, -<value>, <date> )
```

whereas the following returns the timestamp corresponding to midnight of the first day of the quarter for the input timestamp (see https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html)

```
DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', <date> )
```

Hence, as an example, the following

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, '2021-03-29'));
```

is returing `2020-10-01 00:00:00.000`.

If the aim is to return the first day of last month for previous quarters (for example for period =2020-04-01 that would be Q-1 = 2020-03-01, Q-2 = 2019-12-01, Q-3= 2019-09-01):

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, 1
                                , DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, <date>))
                                )
                   ) AS "Q-1",
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, 1
                                , DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', DATEADD(QUARTER, -2, <date>))
                                )
                   ) AS "Q-2",
    DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, 1
                                , DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', DATEADD(QUARTER, -3, <date>))
                                )
                   ) AS "Q-3"
;
```